# Как называется способ передачи данных с подтверждением результата?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология

Например, у меня есть сервер и клиент.

Сервер отправляет клиенту сообщение, а клиент обязательно должен ответить на это сообщение результатом. Да, это некая обратная связь, но может есть какой-нибудь стандарт для таких сообщений или определенное специфическое название?

Comment: TCP  - Transmission Control Protocol

Comment: @Igor мм, а если взять что-то более, например java сокеты. Т.е. мы отправляем некое сообщение и сервер должен знать, что клиент его точно обработал, в этом плане.

Comment: Сокеты и протокол - это ортогональные вещи.

Comment: Но вот абстрагируемся от протоколов, сокетов и прочего. Есть только клиент и есть только сервер. Например, сервер отправляет клиенту большой файл. Клиент либо может его сохранить у себя, либо из-за нехватки места не сохранить. И сервер должен знать результат обработки его сообщения. Есть ли под такую задачу определенный стандарт?

Comment: @Igor TCP это пример конкретной реализации. А вопрос, вроде бы, про более абстрактное определение.

Comment: В целом проблема решена с помощью rabbitmq и ack.